# How to make spaces between border and element without moving element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing the design of an application and then I am using **css** and **bootstrap**. I would like to make space between my left border and my object (element) without moving the object. I would like to move just the left border. Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <legend> hello </legend>
     {{ form_label(form.hello , 'hello') }}
     {{ form_errors(form.hello) }}
     {{ form_widget(form.hello, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 border-left">
      <legend> Ok </legend>
      {{ form_label(form.name , 'Name') }}
      {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
      {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})}}

  </div>
</div>
<style>
 .border-left{
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 200px;
   padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
</style>
```

Then the problem is that the object is moving and the border is in the same place. I think that the **padding-left** property is applied to the object not the border of the object. Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9um4xoe5/)

Comment: Can you provide your full code ?

Comment: `margin-left` will work fine for you. Try it. Otherwise provide full code or sample.

Comment: I tried margin-left and it is doing that also for all the object @Abinthaha , I provide the full code

Comment: it's working fine for me but maybe there is css conflicting, we may help you much if you could add a fiddle with the css

Comment: here is my fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9um4xoe5/) it's not working for me, it moves all the object, I would like to move only the border of the object @Alaa

Comment: Actually, I didn't get your requirement. What did you mean by the object?

Comment: me also didn't get your requirement.

Comment: @Abinthaha in this case it's the text "Ok"

Comment: Now in the fiddle, it seems to be in two lines. the 'hello' and 'Ok'. So you want it in a single line and a space between the 'Ok' and its left-border ?

Comment: exactly @Abinthaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check please if this is what you are looking for?

```
.border-left{
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: relative;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 40px;
   margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Comment: that's not exactly what I want but it resolves a part of my problem. If you visit the same fiddle, my objectif is to make distance between the border of the text "Ok" and the text "Ok" without moving the text "Ok" which means, it's just the border who is moving.

Comment: I need an answer, please